# altair remove or suppress automatically generated plot legend

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, vega, vega-lite, altair

When using the altair package I've noticed that when a chart is created a plot legend is also generated. The follow code:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
alt.renderers.enable('notebook')

cars = data.cars()

alt.Chart(cars).mark_circle().encode(x='Horsepower', 
                                     y='Miles_per_Gallon',
                                     color='Origin',
                                     tooltip=['Name', 'Origin', 'Horsepower', 'Miles_per_Gallon']).interactive()
```

produces this graph:

[image: altair graph]

my question: is there any possible way to suppress this plot legend in the graph output?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is an example for this in the documentation for the `altair` module. You can find it [here](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/customization.html?highlight=legend#adjusting-the-legend).

Here they set the Legend to `None`, which removes the legend.

Here is their example-code:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

iris = data.iris()

alt.Chart(iris).mark_point().encode(
    x='petalWidth',
    y='petalLength',
    color=alt.Color('species', legend=None),
)
```